# How do UI frameworks like Angular / Vue enable event $emits?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been working on Angular2/6 for a year and tried my hands-on VueJS yesterday as part of a small assignment. Maybe I should have known the answer by now but better later than never.

Both Angular / Vue seems to be using something similar in Native JS to propagate events from Child element to parent element, when we call

`$emit('event-name', {custom: 'data'})`

This serves as the basis for Child-to-parent communication, hence the curiosity.

Do these frameworks use **Event bubbling** mechanism of JS?

If so is there a way to pass custom data via event bubbling in JS?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [MDN Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)?

Comment: Cant speak of angular but from what I reckon there is no bubbling of vue's $emit events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, found out the way event's are handled for Child to Parent communication in Angular is through RxJS Subjects.

[Here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/mechanics-of-communication-and-custom-events-binding-in-angular-components-85fd0bdc1f3f) is the article that explains that in detail.